# Identify this cable connector

Tags: connector, power-connector

Please help me identifying this cable connector by part number/source.

4-pins
crimped inline in series on the cable
4 mm pin spacing
18 AWG wire
Has the letters: VEN

[image: 4-pin inline cable connector, 4 mm pin spacing, 18 AWG wire]

Comment: What’s the overall dimensions and pin spacing?

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: please show the mating connector also

Comment: Semi-transparent white, with square pins looks a lot like a "Molex" connector.  But there's probably a thousand Molex variants, and a hundred competitors like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to call those "Panduit" IDC connectors, because that was the popular brand.

IDC is Insulation Displacement Connector which basically means the wire is pushed into a forked contact that cuts into the insulation so you don't have to strip the wires and they can be easily daisy chained by just punching them down along a set of wires. The one pictured appears to have a piece on the top that pushes the wires all down at once and then clips in place.

They aren't as popular as they once were, but you can still find them made by a number of manufacturers.

I've seen a couple of different sizes, probably the most popular pin spacing is specified as 0.156", which would be right about 4mm.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an [Adam Tech MTD series](https://app.adam-tech.com/products/download/data_sheet/241263/mtd-b-xx-x-1-data-sheet.pdf) connector.  Though without the dimensions it's hard to tell for sure.  Also - according to the datasheet - the 18 AWG version should be orange.